# Image Not Found When Using Blackberry Signing Tool

Tags: cordova, blackberry, osx-mountain-lion, zend-studio

```
[exec] dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/RimBlackBerryUSB.framework/Versions/A/RimBlackBerryUSB
 [exec]   Referenced from: /Users/marc/Blackberry/bin/javaloader
 [exec]   Reason: image not found
 [exec] Result: 133
```

I've just had to reinstall mountain lion and setup my Blackberry webworks project (built on Phonegap) using zend studio 10 Beta and Eclipse. When running "ant-target-build" I get the result above - the build completes but the "image not found" is something I have not seen before.

I have updated the paths to the BB SDK in project.properties to the correct directory. Any ideas?

Comment: I have seen that the failure is in blackberry.xml line 52 - which is 

<exec executable="${javaloader}" dir="." failonerror="true">

Comment: Well, is that file present on your system?  (`/Library/Frameworks/RimBlackBerryUSB.framework/Versions/A/RimBlackBerryUSB`)  On mine, it is, of course, and has privileges `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin`.  In other words, it's readable and executable by all users.

Comment: AAh. there is only a RIM_VSP.framework file there. Now I need to find out where this call is being made to change the path. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know that you *should* change the path to RIM_VSP.framework?  I'd be looking to reinstall your toolset so that RimBlackBerryUSB.framework **was** there.  I'm not 100% sure, but I'd guess you need that to debug on a BlackBerry device connected to your Mac.

Comment: Wow. Noob me. I don't have blackberry desktop manager installed, probably the reason this isnt working. Geeez.

Comment: FYI - installing the Blackberry Dekstop Manager for MAC has solved the problem.

Comment: if you don't mind, can you write up that the solution was to install USB drivers thru the desktop manager, add it as an answer, and mark it as solved/accepted?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Blackberry Desktop Manager for MAC was the solution that fixed this problem. Thanks everyone.